# Python generators: correct code recursing a tree

Tags: python, recursion, generator

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        if type(lst) == list:
            self.value = lst[0]
            self.children = lst[1:]
        else:
            self.value = lst
            self.children = []
    @property
    def ChildElements(self):
        return [Node(a) for a in self.children]

    @property
    def GetValue(self):
        return self.value

def node_recurse_generator(node):
    yield node.value
    for n in node.ChildElements:
        node_recurse_generator(n)
```

Node is a simple tree like data structure. The list's first element is always the value of the Node, further elements will be children. If the Node is initiated with something other than a list, that value will be that, and children will be [], an empty list.

```
a = Node([1,[10,20,30],[100,200,300]])
>>> list(node_recurse_generator(a))
[1]
```

Now, it would be great to have a recursive iterator over all the elements, but my generator only yields the first element. Why is this happening?

Comment: Be warned however that your way of constructing a tree is prone to errors: the following code demonstrates this: `b = [1,2,3]` `a = [0,b]` `n = Node(a)` `print(list(node_recurse_generator(n)))` `a[0] = 7 # does not affect n` `b[2] = 4 # affects n` `print(list(node_recurse_generator(n)))` `b = [100,200,300] # from here on, changes in b no longer affect n` `print(list(node_recurse_generator(n)) )`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply calling `node_recurse_generator` recursively isn't enough - you have to `yield` its results:

```
def node_recurse_generator(node):
    yield node.value
    for n in node.ChildElements:
        for rn in node_recurse_generator(n):
            yield rn
```

Comment: As a side note, this is what the `yield from` expression (slated for inclusion in Python 3.3) is going to help with. See PEP 380: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/

Answer (score 8):

As [yak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236036/yak) mentioned in the comment of the top answer, you can also use `yield from` after Python 3.3.

```
def node_recurse_generator(node):
    yield node.value
    for n in node.ChildElements:
        yield from node_recurse_generator(n)
```